# How to create a dynamic distance calculator for selected line feature classes?

Tags: distance, features, dynamic, model

I am working on a project at a park that I am interning at where the goal is to create a single feature with roads and trails together with some way to show the total distance of selected roads and trails.

Currently I have merged the roads and trails features, so I have a single feature with both which contains separate fields with their respective distances.  In its current form I could simply add distances manually from selected trail and road intersections, but I was interested in automating a process to show this.  I was thinking some kind of model (made in ArcGIS model builder) that when run would return an output table of the summed distance of currently selected features.

Question:

1. How can I tell ArcGIS model builder to perform calculations on just selected features?
2. Is there a better way to accomplish the above mentioned task?

Comment: Could you clarify your question regarding features?  I think you might be talking about having merged your roads and trails into a single "featureclass", while maintaining individual road and trail segments.  Is this correct?